# why is onCreate() being called after onConfigurationChanged?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-orientation

I have created an activity and two layouts for the activity, one each for landscape and portrait mode. Both the layouts have same Views and IDs. In the manifest file, I have added
`android:configChanges="orientation"` in the activity.

Now, according to the documentation, the activity is not restarted if I mention configChanges and include the `onConfigurationChanged` method.

```
onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.i("Message","inside oncreate()") ;
}

onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
    Log.i("Message","inside onconfigurationchanged()") ;
}
```

My log is showing both messages when i change the orientation. Is there any way to stop the onCreate() method from being called when the orientation changes?

Comment: Q. Is there any way to stop the onCreate() method from being called when the orientation changes?
A. No way that I know of. :-(

Comment: @g00dy with android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize"  only onConfigurationChanged is called

Comment: @blackbelt - yeah, I forgot about that - shall I remove the comment?

Comment: Do you see multiple time both messages?

Comment: yes, i see both the messages whenever i change the orientation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

maybe you could add more configurations changes that you wish to ignore, since starting of a certain API on android, the orientation consist of other flags , as the [**documentation**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) says about "orientation" :

> The screen orientation has changed — the user has rotated the device.
>   Note: If your application targets API level 13 or higher (as declared
>   by the minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion attributes), then you should
>   also declare the "screenSize" configuration, because it also changes
>   when a device switches between portrait and landscape orientations.

so, please try to use , and tell us if it helped :

```
android:configChanges=orientation|screenSize"
```

here's the documentation about "screenSize":

> The current available screen size has changed. This represents a
>   change in the currently available size, relative to the current aspect
>   ratio, so will change when the user switches between landscape and
>   portrait. However, if your application targets API level 12 or lower,
>   then your activity always handles this configuration change itself
>   (this configuration change does not restart your activity, even when
>   running on an Android 3.2 or higher device). Added in API level 13.

---

EDIT: here's my simple code to show that it works:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Log.i("Message","inside oncreate()");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(final Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        Log.i("Message","inside onconfigurationchanged()");
    }
}
```

manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.test" android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="1.0">

  <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

  <application android:allowBackup="true" android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name="com.example.test.MainActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name" android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
    </activity>
  </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: my application has the minimum SDK set at 8 and target SDK set at 9 :/

Comment: something is wrong on your device or code then, since my code works just fine. i will now post my simple code . in my code, onCreate isn't even called when changing orientation. only onConfigurationChanged gets called.

Comment: You can also differentiate between the 2 cases of onCreate method by using onSaveInstanceState method to save something in the bundle and then checking if savedInstanceState!=null in your onCreate method. During orientation changes, the bundle will not be null and on initial activity create, the bundle will be null.

Comment: @tony yes, and he can also check the orientation itself in the onCreate method and check the previous one by using what you've written (put the current orientation into the bundle and check it on the next onCreate call) .

Comment: @androiddeveloper your onCreate() is not being called after orientation change?

Comment: @R4chi7 no. it doesn't. tested on android 4.2 on my galaxy s3 . which device and android version are you testing? maybe it's also a bug on old versions of android?

Answer (score 1):

Official documentation said that "orientation" in manifest is able to **prevent restarts when the screen orientation changes** and "keyboardHidden" to prevent restarts when the keyboard availability changes.
All you need to do is declare the following codes in your manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"
      android:label="@string/app_name">
```

It works for my project.
If it doesn't work, try to change "**keyboardHidden**" to "**screenSize**".